# How can I "read" a response from the php file I call here using ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am very new to ajax and jquery, but I came across a code on the web which I am manipulating to suit my needs.

The only problem is that I want to be able to respond to the ajax from PHP.

This ajax POSTS to a php page (email.php).

How can I make the email.php reply back if the message is sent or if message-limit is exceeded (I limit the nr of messages sent per each user)?

In other words, I want ajax to take a 1 or 0 from the php code, and for example:

```
  if(response==1){ alert("message sent"); } else { alert("Limit exceeded"); }
```

Here is the last part of the code: (If you need the full code just let me know)

```
var data_string = $('form#ajax_form').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type:       "POST",
    url:        "email.php",
    data:       data_string,
    success:    function() {

    $('form#ajax_form').slideUp('slow').before('');
    $('#success').html('<h3>Success</h3>Your email is has been sent.');
    }//end success function
}) //end ajax call

 return false;

 })
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass an argument to your "success" function.

```
success: function(data)
{
    if(data == '1')
    {
        $('form#ajax_form').slideUp('slow').before('');
        $('#success').html('<h3>Success</h3>Your email is has been sent.');
    }
}
```

And in your php file, you should just echo the response you need

```
if(mail())
{
    echo '1';
}
else
{
    echo '0';
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `success` function of an [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call receives a parameter, usually called `data` though that's up to you, containing the response, so:

```
success: function(data) {
    // Use the data
}
```

(It also receives a couple of other parameters if you want them; more in [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).)

The `data` parameter's type will vary depending on the content type of the response your PHP page sends. If it sends HTML, `data` will be a string containing the HTML markup; if your page sends [JSON](http://json.org), the `data` parameter will be the decoded JSON object; if it's XML, `data` will be an XML document instance.

You **can** use `1` or `0` if you like (if you do, I'd probably set the content type to "text/plain"), so:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data === "1") {
        // success
    }
    else if (data === "0") {
        // failure
    }
    else {
        // App error, expected "0" or "1"
    }
 }
```

...but when I'm responding to Ajax requests, nine times out of ten I send JSON back (so I set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`), because then if I'm using a library like jQuery that understands JSON, I'll get back a nice orderly object that's easy to work with. I'm not a PHP guy, but I believe you'd set the content type via [`setContentType`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.httpresponse-setcontenttype.php) and use [`json_encode`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to encode the data to send back.

In your case, I'd probably reply with:

```
{"success": "true"}
```

or

```
{"success": "false", "errMessage": "You reached the limit."}
```

so that the server-side code can dictate what error message I show the user. Then your `success` function would look like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    var msg;

    if (typeof data !== "object") {
        // Strange, we should have gotten back an object
        msg = "Application error";
    }
    else if (!data.success) {
        // `success` is false or missing, grab the error message
        // or a fallback if it's missing
        msg = data.errMessage || "Request failed, no error given";
    }
    if (msg) {
        // Show the message -- you can use `alert` or whatever
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Anything you echo or return in the php file will be sent back to you jquery post. You should check out this page http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and think about using JSON formatted variables to return so like if you had this in your email script:

echo '{ "reposonse": "1" }';

This pass a variable called response with a value of 1 back to you jquery script. You could then use an if statement how you described.

Answer (score 0):

just have email.php echo a 0 or 1, and then grab the data in the success event of the ajax object as follows...

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'email.php',
  success: function(data) {
    if (data=="1"){
        ...
    }else{
        ...
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

what you do is, you let your ajax file (email.php) print a 1 if successful and a 0 if not (or whatever else you want)

Then, in your success function, you do something like this:

function(data) {

```
$('form#ajax_form').slideUp('slow').before('');
if(data==1){ alert("message sent"); } else { alert("Limit exceeded"); }
$('#success').html('<h3>Success</h3>Your email is has been sent.');
}
```

So you capture the response in the data var of the function. If you a bigger variety in your output, you can set you dataType to "json" and have your php file print a json_encoded string so that you can access your different variables in your response via for example data.success etc.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can only return to AJAX calls, by its output. An AJAX call to a PHP page is essentially the same as a browser requesting for the page.

If your PHP file was something like,

```
<?php
echo "1";
?>
```

You would receive the "1" in your JavaScript success callback,

that is,

```
success: function(data) {
   // here data is "1"
}
```

As an added note, usually AJAX responses are usually done in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format. Therefore, you should format your [PHP replies](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)  in JSON notation.